# what's the event name when you create a new invoice in magento?

Tags: magento, observer-pattern, invoice

when you create an invoice in the admin panel, what is the name of that event for an observer? I've tried *sales_order_invoice_register* and *sales_order_invoice_pay* but it doesn't work.

Comment: This should be `sales_order_invoice_register`. Please define "but it doesn't work" more specifically and show the code that's causing trouble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Magento >= 1.4 there are a couple of options - the best choice would be the event which you've listed, `sales_order_invoice_register`.

Because the invoice model sets the `_eventPrefix` property to `sales_order_invoice`, you can observe `sales_order_invoice_save_after`.

Make sure that you are using the correct event configuration area: adminhtml vs frontend vs global.